# DevTools nuxt-mongoose - Not Connected, Please Check Your Connection

Tags: database, mongodb, vuejs3, nuxt3

I connected a database to my project MongoDB via module nuxt-mongoose but it gives me an error "Not Connected, Please Check Your Connection!" in NuxtDevTools and terrminal "ERROR [nuxt-devtools] RPC error on executing "nuxt-mongoose-rpc:readyState": 14:42:50
[birpc] function "nuxt-mongoose-rpc:readyState" not found". I tried a bunch of solutions to this problem but nothing helps. I posted my project on the network so that you can see the configuration of my project and help in solving this problem https://github.com/anteyku/nuxtErrorDB .[image] [image]

I tried changing package versions but nothing helped